# Reverse engineer not able to connect login failed

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, reverse-engineering

I am trying to do the reverse engineer to add a database to an MVC project.

The command I am using is:

```
C:\Users\Luis\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MoranDBReverse\src\MoranDBRe
verse>dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MoranDBF
irstEdition;Trusted_Connection=True;" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outpu
tDir Models
```

But I am having the following error:

```
Cannot open database "MoranDBFirstEdition" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'xxx\Luis'.
```

The DB exist and is open with windows credentials:

[DBOpen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3IJk.png)

Anybody could advise why the login is failing?

If I want to add the username and credentials how it will be the command, Should I remove the trusted connection and add the credentials like:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MoranDBF
    irstEdition;user id= admin;password= Password!" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outpu
    tDir Models
```

(I tried similar things to this one without success)